# STM32 LTDC difference between pitch and line length

Tags: stm32, ltdc

I don't understand what the difference is between the *color frame buffer pitch* and the *color frame buffer line length* in the `LTDC_CFBLR` register in the LTDC peripheral of the STM32 MCUs.

Here are the descriptions given in the datasheet:

Color frame buffer pitch in bytes:

> These bits define the pitch that is the increment from the start of one line of pixels to the start of the next line in bytes

Color frame buffer line length:

> These bits define the length of one line of pixels in bytes + 3. The line length is computed as follows: active high width * number of bytes per pixel + 3.

These two fields are both contained in the `LTDC_CFBLR` register.

From my understanding, the line length is just the pitch + 3.

Example with a 200x100 px layer in RGB888 encoding (so 3 bytes per pixel):

pitch = 200 × 3 = 600

line length = 200 × 3 + 3 = 603

I don't think my understanding is correct, as I don't see why the LTDC peripheral would need to be given the pitch value twice, and even less so in the same register.

There is this information in the datasheet:

> The number of lines and line length settings define how much data is fetched per frame for every layer. If it is configured to less bytes than required, a FIFO underrun interrupt will be generated if enabled.
> The start address and pitch settings on the other hand define the correct start of every line in memory.

I must admit that I don't really get it.

Comment: In the STM32H7 I'm currently using, `CFBLL = CFBP + 7`, so equally weird (and undocumented, other than what you've already read).

Comment: I've certainly seen lots of video controllers where the *pitch* is the addressing increment to implement +1 in the y-axis.  Whereas the *line length* is the number of byte of pixels on a line.  An example might be a 640 wide line with 8 bit/pixel.  *linelength* is 640 bytes, but *pitch* might be 1024 so that computing the address of a pixel in memory is quick for the CPU which can use shifts instead of multiplies.  It's a variety of alignment padding.  I'm not familiar with this device in particular but it sounds ilke what it's doing. (The +3 is some adjustment required by the hardware.)

Comment: @brhans Seems that the +7 (or +3) is fixed by the hardware, so we should not worry about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...I don't see why the LTDC peripheral would need to be given the pitch value twice, and even less so in the same register.

Not necessarily (twice), because the register is written with the color frame buffer line length AND pitch, which are not the same values when the image is WINDOWED (not all of the image buffer is displayed). One is the entire image line width and the other is the DISPLAYED image line width (plus 3 or 7 bytes added for padding).

See also the post [STM32CubeMX and BUG in LTDC HAL](https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X00009XkgViSAJ/stm32cubemx-and-bug-in-ltdc-hal)

> if you need more than the width of the image width of the visible
> region it is necessary to change the HAL
>
> ...

```
  /* Configures the color frame buffer pitch in byte */   
  LTDC_LAYER(hltdc, LayerIdx)->CFBLR &= ~(LTDC_LxCFBLR_CFBLL | LTDC_LxCFBLR_CFBP);
  // LTDC_LAYER(hltdc, LayerIdx)->CFBLR = (((pLayerCfg->ImageWidth * tmp) << 16) | 
  ((pLayerCfg->ImageWidth * tmp)  + 3)); 
  LTDC_LAYER(hltdc, LayerIdx)->CFBLR  = (((pLayerCfg->ImageWidth * tmp) << 16) | 
  (((pLayerCfg->WindowX1 - pLayerCfg->WindowX0) * tmp)  + 3));
```

> ...

If your hal_ltdc.c is updated (ver > the year of 2018), it has these lines right. And the code shows that the LTDC_LxCFBLR two half-words MAY be different values.

Comment: I see, so for a 200x100px image displayed in a 120x80px layer, assuming 3 bytes per pixel:

line length = 120x3 + 3 = 363;

pitch = 200*3 = 600;

number of lines = 80